# Default code generated by my EF model has errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

This is kind of a noob question, and I am actually a bit embarassed to have not been able to figure it out myself , who knew transition from LinqToSQL to EF will be fraught with nuances like this.

Basically all I did was

1> create a MusicStore SQL database using visual studio 2012 Server Explorer with only one table.

2> Then I added a new `ADO.Net Entity Data Model` `edmx` and generated it using the wizard pointing to my database in step 1.

This gave me a diagram of MusicStore table. Now if I change `Code Generation Strategy` in the properties to `Default` instead of `none`, then this is the code that is generated in the `MusicStoreModel.Designer.cs`.

However, at 
`public MusicStoreEntities() : base("name=MusicStoreEntities", "MusicStoreEntities")`

I get the `has some invalid arguments` .

What am I missing here? a reference?  Any help greatly appreciated.

```
public partial class MusicStoreEntities : ObjectContext
{
    #region Constructors

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new MusicStoreEntities object using the connection string 
    ///found    in the 'MusicStoreEntities' section of the application 
    ///configuration file.
    /// </summary>
    public MusicStoreEntities() : base("name=MusicStoreEntities", "MusicStoreEntities")
    {
        // Also getting a compilation error at the line below
        this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        OnContextCreated();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design. Please refer to the following link for Microsoft's official position: [Entity Framework 5 Code Generation Strategy set to DEFAULT causes errors on all properties of entities](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/779234/entity-framework-5-code-generation-strategy-set-to-default-causes-errors-on-all-properties-of-entities).

> (...) The reason you are seeing these compile errors is because you
>   are re-enabling the legacy code generation without disabling the new
>   T4 based code generation. This means that two sets of classes are
>   being generated. This page provides details on how to revert to
>   ObjectContext code generation -
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556581.

Comment: Great. deleting the both .tt files as per the link fixed it . A+++